# Is there any website where I can speak online to volunteers to practice my English pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

Suppose I'm learning English via the internet. Learning grammar and vocabulary is fine in self-study. However, is there any online resource where I can speak online to volunteers to practice my English pronunciation?

Comment: Not sure if this one is on-topic, but we're here to define! See also [this meta question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/16/55)

Comment: Idk about the On-Topicness either, but I read the Meta Question, and it never hurts to answer.

Comment: A lang-8 user has just mentioned a site called Livemocha. I haven't tried it myself. http://livemocha.com/

Comment: Questions about online resource are never constructive.

Comment: There are many people who are willing to converse over Skype for the purposes of language exchange or whatever else.

Comment: There are some suggestions for finding an on-line partner to practice with in the [Resources for learning English wiki](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/953/9161) on meta.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything specifically designed for this, however you can use a site such as [Omegle (NSFW)](http://omegle.com) however your people there aren't exactly the best people, and you are subject to human nature, i.e. inappropriate body parts :D

Same for sites like [Chat Roulette (NSFW)](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=chat%20roulette&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://chatroulette.com/&ei=U2gAUYmZDKKG2wWUn4HoBg&usg=AFQjCNFvG8zCVTLScaKH8Ai5nk74IJHgYg&sig2=_BjQK0XHiGE87etyZ1x5hg&bvm=bv.41248874,d.b2I) as well. However, they tend to block nudity (better). Other alternatives are to post audio on [YouTube](http://youtube.com), or use something like [Rosetta Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com), which evaluates pronunciation.

Comment: Make it a CW, so that it can serve better.