# Recommended ways to regularly talk with people to practice English

Tags: american-english

For those people who don't live in a country where English is used in daily life, sustaining English speaking skills is very very hard.

I myself spent many hours looking for conversation groups and random people to talk with in many places online. Usually people don't trust someone they don't know and they don't want to talk much.

I'm not looking for paid platforms since it is kind of superficial and a bit boring. It's not natural. When you talk to someone continuously, it is more natural and enjoyable.

So, could you please share some ideas that can help people to practice their English "speaking" online?

How to find people who might be interested in taking time to talk online? How to gain their trusts or attention?

Comment: "How to find ...?", "How to gain ...?", these questions will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. NC.

Comment: noarm, welcome to ELL!  It is a site for writing, not speaking, but recently lang-8.com was recommended to me. You post journal entries and native speakers edit them. I gave it a try as I'm learning Spanish, and it works pretty well. As far as those saying the question is a bit off-topic for the site, they're correct. How to get people to talk to you is a bit off-topic. But if you edit your question and instead ask if there are any websites or online resources directed at this, perhaps you'll get a nice answer! I don't know if such a site exists, we'll see!

Comment: @WendiKidd I love lang-8!  It's true that it's for writing rather than speaking, but some users are willing to practice talking on Skype if you ask.  I've heard users call it a "language exchange" where you spend half the time talking in your native language and the other half talking in theirs.

Comment: You can surf Skype for people who're willing to use video calls for language exchange. I have a Skype account, but I refuse everyone I don't know simply because I have no time & no interest in making online "friends" -- it's not a matter of trust, just time & shared interests. Other folks have different feelings about that. If you find a simpatico person in a chat group, you might suggest a Skype video connection. Here in Taiwan, people sometimes do face-to-face language exchanges at coffee shops.

Comment: Possible duplicate, which is also closed: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76/is-there-any-website-where-i-can-speak-online-to-volunteers-to-practice-my-engli

Comment: There are some suggestions for finding an on-line partner to practice with in the [Resources for learning English wiki](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/953/9161) on meta.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to meet people using Omegle or Chatroulette (although it sometimes may be difficult to find decent people or ones that actually speak English well enough for your purposes). If you do find someone, you can mail them or Facebook chat them, or even use Skype. Worked for me multiple times, and I still talk to someone daily.